How to make an Office dialog box look more like Microsoft's reported message popup?
I am displaying a dialog box in an Outlook add-in (Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync). Is there a way to make it look more like the popup that you see after reporting a message using Microsoft's built-in "Report" button?
Here is what my popup looks like.

The popup I am referring to that Microsoft displays after reporting an email looks like this:

So, I'm wanting to remove the address bar and the window title ("Outlook PWA") in the dialog box that I'm displaying. Here is the HTML that I'm displaying for the content of the dialog box:
<head><title>Hi</title></head>
<div>
    Hello world 2!
</div>

And here is how I'm calling the file that contains that HTML:
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://{website}/test.html', {height: 30, width: 20, promptBeforeOpen: false});

Thanks!

Try adding "displayInIframe: true"

Ah, that seems to be the type of popup I'm looking for! However, now when I use that I get this error and nothing loads in the popup: [Report Only] This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment.  Would you happen to know what is causing that? (The HTML file is on the same domain that the add-in code is hosted on.)
